# Как на сервере Apache при запросе на несуществующий домен перенаправлять все на 404

Tags: apache2

Как на сервере *Apache* при запросе на несуществующий домен перенаправлять все на 404?

Comment: а что сейчас происходит «при запросе на несуществующий домен»?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Если я Вас правильно понял то:

Создайте два **VirtualHost**, таким образом при обращение на домен которого нет будет отдаваться 404

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yy>
  # Default vhost
  ServerName *
  # force to return 404 for all non recognized requests
  DocumentRoot "/usr/local/nonexistent"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yy>
  ServerName существующий домен.com
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

В директории `www` на сайте должен быть файл `.htaccess`
Там нужно будет прописать

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error_pages/new404.html
```